# Integer parsing not working

Tags: java

```
public static int parseInt(String s) {
    int val = 0;
    for (int i = s.length() - 1, times = 1; i >= 0; i--, times *= 10) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        int x = c - '0';
        if (x >= 0 && x < 10)
            ;
        else
            throw new NumberFormatException("not an int '" + c + "'");

        x *= times;
        val += times;
    }
    return val;
}
```

I am making my own int parser like Integer.parseInt(String); and it doesn't work properly. I am passing this to the method "435435332" and it prints this back to me "111111111"

Comment: You're not adding `x` onto `val` in any kind of way. You are just adding on multiples of 10.

Comment: `if(condition);else{doSomething();}` can (and probably should) be rewritten as `if(!(condition)){doSomething();}`. In your case you are probably looking for `if (!Character.isDigit(c)) throw...`.

Comment: oo thank you. you are right you can put that as a answer it works perfect now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not adding `x` onto `val` in any kind of way. You are just adding on powers of 10.

Answer (score 1):

Change `val += times;` to `val += x;`